# unable to access wildfly on remote server

Tags: vpn, remote-access

I've been given access to a CentOS server over IKEv2 VPN along with a certificate and private key. I've imported the certificate to my macOS Keychain Access and have setup my VPN connection. All good so far. I can access the server over terminal using `ssh -i <private.key> user@private-ip`

I've installed jboss on the CentOS server and have deployed a simple hello world war file.

My issue starts here. I can't access the page from my local. Since I'm on the VPN, I thought that I could just open Chrome (on my local) and type in `http://<private-ip>:8080/hellWorld` and see the hello world page, but instead I get

> "This site can't be reached xxx.xxx.x.xx took too long to respond."

I have verified using netstat that port 8080 and 9990 are open.  I've also enabled remote access by updating standalone.xml and setting the management and public interface inet addresses to `0.0.0.0`.  Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong here/missing? Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably have a firewall running, so add the output of `iptables -nvL`.

Comment: Piotr, here's the output: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UU0bP9Sivnhxd868HH6HTGsjhzrJWE-WTVOnhVeb0PM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

In CentOS you have to open port 8080 explicitly because as per default all ports are closed by `firewalld`.

To check if `firewalld` is running enter

```
systemctl status firewalld.service
```

If it is active then enter this:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=8080/tcp
firewall-cmd --reload
```

and try again to send a request to your app.

Comment: thank you.  firewall is on, but adding port 8080 as instructed has not resolved my issue.  i even tried turning off firewalld and still no luck.

Comment: From your firewall config above (in a comment) you unblocked the port. If you run `iptables -nvL IN_public_allow` you should see the packet count raise for every connection.

Comment: Thanks, Piotr.  Could you please clarify what you mean by "you should see the packet count raise for every connection"?
Running your suggested command returns the following.  I don't see any changes after hitting the <centos_ip>:8080 from my laptop.

 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    1    96 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED

Comment: Could you do a `curl -I http://<private-ip>:8080/hellWorld` from your laptop and add the output to your question?

Comment: Digijay, when I ran your command, it sat there for a few mins then returned the following:
```curl: (7) Failed to connect to <private-key> port 8080: Operation timed out```

Do i need to pass the private key to curl in the same manner in which I connect to the server itself? Ex: ```ssh -i user.key user@<private-key>```

Thanks a lot for all your help thus far.

Comment: No, you wouldn't need to. I get the impression that your JBoss App might be responding other than expected, could you call it directly from localhost?

Comment: let me start over:
so here's what happens if i try curl localhost
[user@host ~]$ curl localhost
curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:80; Connection refused
if i try to curl 8080 though i get the jboss page:
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo curl localhost:8080
<!--
  ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
  ~ Copyright (c) 2014, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
  ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
.
.
.
still no luck accessing it from my laptop though